# Redirect URLS with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, server-side, httpd.conf

I'm trying to redirecting URLS received on my Apache web server. Basically when I type

> localhost/index.html

I want the website to redirect me to a `readme.html` file inside the *htdocs*. `index.html` and `readme.html` files both are saved in the *htdocs*. I looked at the Apache documentation but I cannot seem to get this working. Below I have included the code I have wrote so far inside the `httpd.conf` file.

```
DocumentRoot "usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/htdocs">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.html readme.html [PT]
</Directory>
```

I have tried on my browser looking for "localhost/index.html" , however I am seeing the index.html page. Unless I am looking at it wrong. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
<Directory "usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
#your other code here#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ readme.html [R,NC]
</Directory>
```

Its always good to clear cache and delete temporary internet files.