# mod_rewrite - How to rewrite to a page based on ip address

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, directory, server-side, httpd.conf

I have been keep asking questions related to mod_rewrite so firstly sorry to spam you all with the same topic. problem I am facing now is that I want to redirect my web page based on the user ip address. So when you access "localhost/index" it should redirect you to example.html if the ip address starts off with 10 however if not I want to redirect the users to the readme.html page. readme.html, index.html and example.html are in the the same directory (htdocs).

This is the code so far;

```
DocumentRoot "usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
<Directory "/htdocs">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10 
RewriteRule ^index.html$ readme.html [R,NC]
</Directory>
```

Tried doing this way;

//`RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^!10
//`RewriteRule ^ index.html$ example.html [R,NC]

But this doesn't work

So for now I am only allowing users which has an ip address starting with 10 to access the site.

I looked into the documentation and couldn't find a way around it and that is the reason for this post, please can someone help

Thanks

Comment: if you want to see the previous post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787392/redirect-urls-with-apache-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10 
RewriteRule ^index.html$ example.html [R,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ readme.html [R,NC]
```

Read more about [rewriteRule R flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)